# Send push notification to Android repackage bar file in Blackberry OS using FCM

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

Can I send the push notification to Android application in Blackberry OS 10.3 using FCM push notification.

If not, Is there any way to send the push notification to blackberry OS devices.

Comment: AFAIK, BB10 does not support Play Services and hence would not support FCM.

Comment: so is there any way to send push notification.

Comment: I forget if BB10 has its own push messaging system. Otherwise, you would be looking at using other Internet technologies (MQTT, XMPP, WebSockets, etc.), bearing in mind that it difficult to keep those connections going 100% of the time.

Comment: @CommonsWare https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-Android-Runtime-Samples/tree/master/SamplePushClient is its working in Blackberry ?

Comment: I had tested the same application using Firebase in Android by SENDER_ID and its working

Comment: "s its working in Blackberry ? " -- I have no idea.

Comment: But even i have entered the all details in android.cfg file it show "Please check the push credential details"

Answer (score 1):

Confirming @CommonsWare's comment, there is currently no FCM support for BlackBerry OS.

For the available Push Notification services for BlackBerry, you should check out the [Official BlackBerry documentations like this one](http://developer.blackberry.com/services/push/).

Comment: I got one sample https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-Android-Runtime-Samples/tree/master/SamplePushClient, But its not working